# Pandas' SettingWithCopyWarning inevitable?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

A given column *a* of a data frame `df` contains strings with line-breaks. I split them into a list of strings via

```
df.a = df.a.str.split('\n', expand=False)
```

However, I get the warning

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
>   using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   self[name] = value

However, I do not see any possibility to do it with `.loc` as suggested in the warning or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas).

Am I right?

Comment: Strange I can't reproduce your error. Can you post a minimal example of your data?

Comment: This kind of error is very confused, because obviolusly use line of code bellow problematic line. So I guess problem is in line above `df.a = df.a.str.split('\n', expand=False)`. Maybe need [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49316818/2901002)

Comment: Thanks you, guys! This were exactly the hints I oversaw!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jpp and @jezreal, the problem was in the previous code lines:

```
df = root_of_all_evil[some_selection]
df.a = df.a.str.split('\n', expand=False)
```

The solution is simple now as suggest by @jezreal:

```
df = root_of_all_evil[some_selection].copy()
df.a = df.a.str.split('\n', expand=False)
```